# Laravel5 How to access public folder from controller

Tags: image, laravel, path, controller, public

I'm new on Laravel and some little trick escape me.

i have a controller where i need to list  pictures in a public folder ( ex: public/images/album/Ecosse), but i don't known how to acceed it.
i have always the no directory error.
Can you explain me how it's working ?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\AlbumsRepository;
use File;

class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    protected $albumsRepository;

    public function __construct(AlbumsRepository $albumsRepository)

    {
        $this->albumsRepository = $albumsRepository;
    }
    public function show($n)
    {
        $album = $this->albumsRepository->getById($n);

        $files1 = File::allFiles(asset('images/albums/'.$album->titre));
        foreach ($files1 as $key => $value)
           {
              if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
              {
                 if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
                 {
                    $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    $result[] = $value;
                 }
              }
           } 
        return view('album')->with('album', $album);
    }
}
```

Thank for your help.
Maxime

Answer (score 1):

use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(public_path('images/albums/'.$album->titre));
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // both file and directory will be iterated.
}
```

Comment: sorry for late answer but i'm in local, maybe it's change something  because i have this now for directory : C:\wamp64\www\photo\public\images/albums/Ecosse.  Maybe i need to replace \ by / ?

Comment: @MaximeBaude No need to replace manually, windows can recognize both '\' and '/' directory delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I access my public folder from controller by using `url()` function like:

```
url('uploads/images/user_image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works 
`public_path('cow.jpg')`